# What should I look out for when combining Autolayout and positioning in iOS?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am working on an iOS project that uses auto layout to set up a view with a scroll view and a stack as the scroll view's content.

All works well, and I can add UIViews until the cows come home to the stack and it does what is expected.

However the question now arises when I am about to implement the user-definable layouts for the reporting view.

The stack holds a view dedicated to user defined layouts.

The user will define the data output (for example "benefits") and the origin (top left corner) and that view will be placed there. They can place as many or as few views and pieces of data that are made available to them in this manner. They will have no understanding of auto layout and hence will solely rely on the exact positioning of these views via the top left corner and their size.

Is there anything I should be aware of before starting this phase of the project? My concern is the mixing/matching of auto layout in the global layout and exact positioning inside this one specific view.

Looking for input on caveats, code that I MUST include (for example any flags that should be set) and so forth.

Thanks for any sort of help,
D

Comment: What if the device orientation changes? Wouldn't the user-defined views look weird?

Comment: For many cases (but definitely no all) you can get away by setting `someView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]` .

Comment: @Sweeper ... the app has a set orientation at this time ... discussions with the team have been back and forth between seperate designs for portrait/landscape and also auto calculating intent of the positioning. For now, however ... definitely one orientation.

Comment: @Yonat - so in general, the views I want to set by precise placement (origin and size - hence frame) I would set their autoresizingMask has you have described?

Comment: Yes. And keep the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as true.

Comment: @Yonat - a clarification if you will ... if I have a UIView defined which contains other UIViews such as UILabels, UIButtons etc that are created using auto layout constraints, can the base UIView be positioned as described while its contents are placed using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, it can actually go both ways: auto-layout superview with autoresizing-mask subviews, and also autoresizing-mask superview with auto-layout subviews.

Comment: Great! I will whip up a test project to check this all out and go from there. Thank you for the help. In the case it works I would like to give you a +1 .. how do you do that in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

My concept was a little to involved for the suggestions given, however I did develop a solution that allowed the user to position the widgets by origin (top left corner) while still using AutoLayout.

For those interested, I created a "dummy" UIView to hold all of the user positioned widgets and then created Autolayout constraints based on the top and left anchors of this view.

Since the widgets are created by reading the layout from a Dictionary, if they make changes to the layout, I simply remove/refresh the layout if they make a change.

Thanks once again for the nuggets, without which I would not have thought of this solution.

D